# Why won't windows 10 allow me to upgrade without first entering windows 7 product key?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, product-key

Ok, so I am running windows 7. I previously upgraded to 10 smoothly, however I blue screened frequently due to my graphics cards being ancient and not supported. I rolled back to windows 7 for the time being via the control panel option. Everything was fine and now i have ordered a new graphics card. I installed the new card today, and after installing its driver, windows started saying it was not a genuine copy. I don't have product key to hand but i now want to upgrade to windows 10 again but it won't let me until I give my product key for 7... I thought even pirated versions were meant to get the upgrade... So why won't it let me on this situation? I have no idea where product key is ...

Comment: in microsoft FAQ http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activating-windows-faq#1TC=windows-7 there is not a possible escenary where your lost product key is given back, so if is lost, consider to get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple answer,  Microsoft has answered before and is still applicable.

You cannot upgrade a non-genuine version of Windows , either 7 or 8 or 8.1 and definitely will not allow Vista or XP to upgrade, your key has now been migrated to windows 10.

just read it on the upgrade to windows 10 website!!

Your original Product key has been migrated to windows 10 and hence will not activate windows 7 anymore.   Try reinstalling a clean copy of 10 using the your copy of the key, it may work, you can then upgrade the graphics card or else you will need to talk to MS.
Good luck.